# Prove that $\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)$ is an odd function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, logarithms, hyperbolic-functions

The inverse hyperbolic sine $\sin^{-1}(x) = \mathrm{arcsinh}(x)$ is an odd function. This can be proved by manipulating the expression $\mathrm{arcsinh}(-x) = y$ as shown [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_Hyperbolic_Sine_is_Odd_Function).

But how to prove it through [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_sine) instead?

$$\mathrm{arcsinh}(x) = \log \left( x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1} \right)$$

**My attempt:**

I applied [this rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Summation/subtraction), so obtaining

$$\mathrm{arcsinh}(-x) = \log \left( \sqrt{x^2 + 1} \right) + \log \left( 1 - \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \right)$$

This does not seem the expression of $\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)$ with opposite sign. How to proceed?

Comment: $(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})(-x+\sqrt{x^2+1})=1$

Comment: The rule pulls you away from the solution, don't use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\text{arsinh}(x)+\text{arsinh}(-x)=\log(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)+\log(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)=\log(x^2+1-x^2).$$

You can conclude.